# Preserving variable names in scope set by Webpack in JSX sourcemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, jsx

I have a working Hello World example using Webpack, Babel and React. When I set a breakpoint in Chrome DevTools, Chrome says all imported symbols are undefined in the current scope.

[image]

If I let the code run, it works as expected. React successfully renders "Hello, World!" The problem is that Chrome sees the wrong scope.

EDIT: This happens because Webpack renames my variables. **How can I preserve my variable names so that I can debug more comfortably?**

My webpack configuration is below.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');

var public_dir = __dirname + '/public';

module.exports = {
    entry: './behavior/house/entry.jsx',

    cache: true,
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename: 'behavior.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'behavior.js.map'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        root: [
            path.resolve('./behavior/house'),
            path.resolve('./behavior/vendor')
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: public_dir,
        filename: 'behavior.js',
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        colors: true,
        noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            server: { baseDir: [public_dir] }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'source-map'
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                cacheable: true,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                    retainLines: true,
                    cacheDirectory: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that too. If you look at the list of variables in the scope, the imports show up as something like `_React` or `_react2`.

It looks like webpack renames some of the variables when it bundles all the files together. The sourcemaps keep your breakpoints in sync, but the console doesn't map your variable names back to your es6 source code.